# Is there any way to evaluate $e^{H_n} = … + O(\frac{1}{n})$, where $H_n$ is $n$-th harmonic number?

Tags: asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

I know, that $H_n = \log n + \gamma + O(1)$, but in that case $e^{H_n} = e^{\log n + \gamma + O(1)} = n e^\gamma e^{O(1)}$ - I can't use this. How can I get this $O(\frac1n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another term.  $$H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + \dfrac{1}{2n} + O\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yeah, I know this formula too, but how can I extract $O(\frac1{n^2})$ from exponent?

Comment: I mean, according to the formula, $e^{H_n} = n e^{\gamma + \frac1{2n}}  e^{O(\frac1{n^2})}$. Still not $… + O(\frac1{n})$.  (or $… + O(\frac1{n^2})$, that's not the point).

Comment: @Arsen $$ e^{O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\quad\text{ and }\quad
n O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$